# Downloading a pdf with jquery using jax-rs

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, pdf, jax-rs

I'll try to download a pdf file using jquery and jax-rs. the pdf file will be created dynamically.

For testing purposes, I've just set a local pdf file. I need to parse some parameters for generating the pdf later. I'll post these params to the server and the server sends back a pdf file. Now what can I do on JS side to finally see the donwload-window?

Java-Side:

@Path("/chatexport/")
public class ChatExportController {

```
private static final String FILE_PATH = "c:\\own\\test.pdf";

@POST
@Path("/")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces("application/pdf")
public Response getFile(List<ChatMessage> chatMessageList) {
    File file = new File(FILE_PATH);

    ResponseBuilder response = Response.ok((Object) file);
    response.header("Content-Disposition",
            "attachment; filename=new-android-book.pdf");
    return response.build();

}
```

Javascript-Side:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: EXPORT_URL,
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: JSON.stringify([{authorId:"1",timestamp:123,content:"Test123"}]),
        dataType: "application/pdf",
        success: function (json, status) {
            if (status != "success") {
                console.log("Error loading data");
                return;
            }
            console.log("Data loaded!");
        },
        error: function (result, status, err) {
            console.log("Error loading data", err);
            return;
        }
    });
```

The err Object in the error callback that is thrown says this:
`No conversion from text to application/pdf`

Answer (score 0):

For a similar problem, I used this technique: Create an invisible iframe within the page when clicked on the download button (or when the download event is triggered), and set the source of the iframe as the PDF URL. You should also keep the Content-Disposition header for this technique. The file is automatically downloaded.

Comment: Well, I have no specific download url just for the pdf file. The problem is I need to send JSON data before to make sure the pdf is generated. and then download it.

Comment: You can still use this. Create a (dynamic) form, which has a target to the (hidden) iframe. You can POST using this form, and the response can still be downloaded.